# Convert BufferedInputStream into image

Tags: java, mysql, web-services, jersey, inputstream

Im having trouble turning my blob into a buffered image so I can use it. I'm getting a blob (jpg image) back from my database I uploaded using inputstream. In my database it is stored as BufferedInputStream I notice. I get the blob just fine, its a bunch of weird symbols and says its a jpg so the image has to be fine. Can anyone spot what I'm doing wrong? Maybe im converting it wrong? At image = ImageIO.read(new ByteArrayInputStream(data)); Image returns null.

```
@GET
@Path("{id}")
 @Produces("image/*")
public Response post(@PathParam("id") String id) throws IOException {
    Connection con = connection();
    Blob blob = getPhoto(con);
    BufferedImage image = null;
    byte[] data = null;
    int blobLength = 0;
    try {
        blobLength = (int) blob.length();
        data = blob.getBytes(1, blobLength);
        image = ImageIO.read(new ByteArrayInputStream(data));
    //  ImageIO.write(image, "JPEG", new File("C:/Users/Nicolas/Desktop/image.jpg"));
    } catch (SQLException e2) {
        e2.printStackTrace();
    }  

    return Response.ok(image).build();
}
```

How I write to database

```
public void postPhoto(Connection con, InputStream uploadedInputStream){

String mySQL = "INSERT INTO photos (photo) values (?)";
PreparedStatement pStmt = con.prepareStatement(mySQL);
pStmt.setBlob(1, uploadedInputStream);
pStmt.execute();
}
```

How I send the file to my servlet

```
var fileInput = document.getElementById('file');
var file = fileInput.files[0];
var formData = new FormData();
formData.append("file", file);

var parameters="first="+firstName+"&last="+lastName+"&file="+file;

xmlhttp.open("post","http://localhost:8080/restService/api/submitinfo",true);
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
xmlhttp.send(formData);
```

Comment: Is data filled with bytes after `blob.getBytes()` ?

Comment: yes it is filled with bytes and is pretty much the same amount of bytes as the original jpg

Comment: I would check the file first. Either write `data` to File and try opening it with some image viewer. If you have valid jpg file try to read it from by `ImageIO.read(new File(...);`. I think that the problem is that data isn't valid image.

Comment: Ok I did as you said and windows photo view said the image appears to be damaged then I opened it in photo shop and it displayed just fine.. Hmmm.. Im so confused and have used a lot of time on this

Comment: You could try using `ImageIO.createImageInputStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(data))` and then pass the result of this to `ImageIO.read` instead, but to be honest I doubt it would work.  Can you post the code you used to write it...

Comment: Hey madProgrammer, How I post it to mydatabase? I edited that for you.

Comment: also tried what you said did not work /:

Comment: Well, if windows photo view says that image appears to be damaged, it may have corrupted header or some other issues. Have you been trying with valid image?

Comment: How is the `uploadedInputStream` created?

Comment: public String post(@FormDataParam("file") InputStream uploadedInputStream)  ---  I just get it from a simple http file post request using application/x-www-form-urlencoded

Comment: Mgorgon happens with all images ive tried

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Start by verifying that `uploadedInputStream` is a valid image, prehaps by writing it out using `ImageIO.write`.  You can always use `ImageIO.read` to read the image back in and write it back out to a `ByteArrayInputStream` ;)

I did a quick test using H2 database.

A few things I noted.  `Blob#length` returns a `long`, while `Blob#getBytes` expects an `int`, this could mean you're truncating the byte stream.

Also, from the documentation of H2, it would seem that the `Blob` contents is not kept in memory, so I use the `getBinaryStream` instead.

```
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.sql.Blob;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;

public class TestImageDatbase {

    private Connection con;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new TestImageDatbase();
    }

    public TestImageDatbase() {
        try {
            clearDatabase();
            saveImage();
            loadImage();
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException | SQLException | IOException exp) {
            exp.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    protected Connection getConnection() throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException {
        Class.forName("org.h2.Driver");
        return DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:h2:d:\\Image", "sa", "");
    }

    protected void clearDatabase() throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException, SQLException {

        Connection con = null;
        PreparedStatement stmt = null;

        try {

            con = getConnection();
            System.out.println("Cleaning database");
            stmt = con.prepareStatement("delete from images");
            int updated = stmt.executeUpdate();
            System.out.println("Updated " + updated + " rows");

        } finally {
            try {
                stmt.close();
            } catch (Exception e) {
            }
            try {
                con.close();
            } catch (Exception e) {
            }
        }

    }

    protected void saveImage() throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException, SQLException {

        Connection con = null;
        PreparedStatement stmt = null;
        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = null;
        ByteArrayInputStream bais = null;

        try {

            baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

            File source = new File("/path/to/file");
            System.out.println("Source size = " + source.length());
            BufferedImage img = ImageIO.read(source);
            ImageIO.write(img, "png", baos);

            baos.close();

            bais = new ByteArrayInputStream(baos.toByteArray());

            con = getConnection();
            stmt = con.prepareStatement("insert into images (image) values (?)");
            stmt.setBinaryStream(1, bais);
            int updated = stmt.executeUpdate();
            System.out.println("Updated " + updated + " rows");

        } finally {
            try {
                bais.close();
            } catch (Exception e) {
            }
            try {
                baos.close();
            } catch (Exception e) {
            }
            try {
                stmt.close();
            } catch (Exception e) {
            }
            try {
                con.close();
            } catch (Exception e) {
            }
        }

    }

    protected void loadImage() throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException, SQLException {

        Connection con = null;
        PreparedStatement stmt = null;
        ResultSet rs = null;

        try {

            con = getConnection();
            stmt = con.prepareStatement("select image from images");
            rs = stmt.executeQuery();

            while (rs.next()) {

                System.out.println("Getting blob");
                Blob blob = rs.getBlob(1);
                System.out.println("Reading image");
                BufferedImage img = ImageIO.read(blob.getBinaryStream());
                System.out.println("img = " + img);
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, new JScrollPane(new JLabel(new ImageIcon(img))));

            }

        } finally {
            try {
                rs.close();
            } catch (Exception e) {
            }
            try {
                stmt.close();
            } catch (Exception e) {
            }
            try {
                con.close();
            } catch (Exception e) {
            }
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you Mad! Finally someone was able to see the kinks for me. Trying to learn, Still new at this!

Comment: It's been a very long time since I had to write any serious SQL, so it was a learning curve for me to ;)

Comment: @MadProgrammer you are always ready to help,+1 for good answer,whenever I see a swing question I remember about you

Comment: @JqueryLearner not sure  its a good answer, but gives the OP some things to try ;)